# How is plus-equals acting on this array of structs?

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I was reading over some of the source code behind pngquant ([here](https://github.com/ImageOptim/libimagequant))

I got confused when I saw plus-equals seemingly assigning a new value to an array of structs (`base += r` in the code snippet below):

```
static void hist_item_sort_range(hist_item base[], unsigned int len, unsigned int sort_start)
{
    for(;;) {
        const unsigned int l = qsort_partition(base, len), r = l+1;

        if (l > 0 && sort_start < l) {
            len = l;
        }
        else if (r < len && sort_start > r) {
            base += r; len -= r; sort_start -= r;
        }
        else break;
    }
}
```

The `hist_item` definition is given as:

```
typedef struct {
    f_pixel acolor;
    float adjusted_weight,   // perceptual weight changed to tweak how mediancut selects colors
          perceptual_weight; // number of pixels weighted by importance of different areas of the picture

    float color_weight;      // these two change every time histogram subset is sorted
    union {
        unsigned int sort_value;
        unsigned char likely_colormap_index;
    } tmp;
} hist_item;
```

I apologize ahead of time, because I'm sure to those in the know this must be a really dumb question, but how is plus-equals operating on `base`, which appears to be an array of structs, and some integer `r`? It seems to me that this operation should be undefined for the combination of those two types.

I haven't had to write C for almost ten years, and I'm admittedly pretty rusty; however, searching for about thirty minutes only turned up answers to the wrong questions, and any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `hist_item base[]` is actually decayed to `hist_item* base`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying - so `base += r` is just pointer arithmetic

Comment: @UnholySheep thanks! That's exactly what I needed to know.

Comment: I misunderstood the question. As @UnholySheep already says, in C you cannot pass arrays as parameter, they are **always passed by reference**. This is obtained by their automatic decay to pointers to same object forming the array. So they're de-facto pointers, and the `+=` operation follows the pointers arithmetic. In the specific case after `base+=r;`, `base` points to `r` elements ahead.

Comment: @UnholySheep 1) if you respond as an answer, I'll accept it ASAP. 2) In your answer, could you also clarify one aspect of the pointer arithmetic here; namely, if the array pointer is incremented and then the array's value is referenced, &base[0] for example, is the indexing offset by the incrementation? Put more simply, is &base[0] AFTER base +=1 the same as &base[1] before incrementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in [What is array decaying?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying)

```
static void hist_item_sort_range(hist_item base[], unsigned int len, unsigned int sort_start)
```

becomes

```
static void hist_item_sort_range(hist_item* base, unsigned int len, unsigned int sort_start)
```

Where `base` is a pointer to the first element of the array. Therefore `base += r;` performs simple pointer arithmetic, i.e.: modifies the pointer to point to an offset of `r` elements from the start of the array.
Due to the `+=` the original pointer is modified, so any access happens with offset from the now pointed to element.

To use the example from the comment:
After `base += 1;` accessing the "first" element via `&base[0];` yields a pointer to the same element as `&base[1];` before the increment